# Base64 to Bitmap in compose multiplatform?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, compose-multiplatform

I can easily convert base64 to bitmap in Android using below code

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.URL_SAFE);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

But i can't access `BitmapFactory` in compose multiplatform as it belongs to android only.
So how can i convert base64 to image in compose multiplatform?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
val encodedImageData = Base64.Default.decode(encodedImage)
val image = Image.makeFromEncoded(encodedImageData).toComposeImageBitmap()
```